# String to data as JSON Swift3

Tags: json, xcode, swift3

im working with URLRequest in swift3.
For consume a rest service I need add a body into URLResquest, for this I use this String:

```
 public func jsonPush() -> String {
    let date = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(60)

    let text: String =
        "{" +
            "\"action\": {" +
            "  \"content\": {" +
            "  \"default\": \"VIP\"" +
            "}," +
            "\"@type\": \"SendLocalMessageAction\"," +
            " \"bgAlert\": { " +
            " }, " +
            " \"contentType\": \"text\\/plain\"" +
            "}," +
            "\"draft\": false, " +
            "\"trigger\": { " +
            "\"time\": "+"\(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"+", " +
            "\"@type\": \"TimeTrigger\" " +
            "}, " +
            "\"config\": { " +
            "\"name\": \"Llego el cliente VIP Daniel\" " +
            "}, " +
            "\"audience\": { " +
            "\"type\": \"UserIds\", " +
            "\"ids\": [ " +
            "\"DGHCiwUTbDYnmSOOe7CwKKEB5SA2\", " +
            "\"FgLN69yCR1RzKY23fFdYhTD2HZg1\" " +
            "] " +
            " } " +
    "} "
    print("El json es:\(text) como valor final")
        return text
}
```

but when I try to send data

```
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: uriNotifications + appId)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue(autenticacion, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let session = URLSession.shared
               request.httpBody=jsonPush() as? Data
        session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            print("Entered the completionHandler")
                       if(error != nil) {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                //  let posts = json["posts"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
                print("Cantidad")
                print(json)
            } catch let parseError {
                print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
                let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                print("raw response: \(responseString)")
            }
```

The response is:

> {
>       error = "Bad Request";
>       "error_description" = "Could not parse JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input"; }

But if I try with the output:

> {"action": {  "content": {  "default": "VIP"},"@type":
>   "SendLocalMessageAction", "bgAlert": {  },  "contentType":
>   "text/plain"},"draft": false, "trigger": { "time": 1497373512981.26,
>   "@type": "TimeTrigger" }, "config": { "name": "Llego el cliente VIP
>   Daniel" }, "audience": { "type": "UserIds", "ids": [
>   "DGHCiwUTbDYnmSOOe7CwKKEB5SA2", "FgLN69yCR1RzKY23fFdYhTD2HZg1" ]  } }

The response is good:

[image]

Comment: Why do you create the JSON string *manually* rather than creating a collection type and use `JSONSerialization.data(with:`? Then you get even `Data` for free.

Comment: Beacause, I need only change one field....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue most probably on line `request.httpBody=jsonPush() as? Data` as of method `jsonPush` return `String` you are directly type casting it to to `Data` that is wrong instead of that use `data(using:)` with string to get data.

```
request.httpBody = jsonPush().data(using: .utf8)
```

Comment: @DanielORTIZ Welcome mate :)